# How to prohibit a parameter from being filled with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

So I have this constructor and as you can I have all of the parameters set to be required except for the id. This isn't a big deal but I was wondering if there was annotation that would make the id parameter not available to be filled in.

So I don't mess something up in the future and fill the id in by accident, because this is being entered into a database.

Thank you in advance! I'm new to Flutter but am loving it so far and this community rocks! <3

```
    //Constructor
    NotifierInstance({

      //Identification
      this.id,
      @required this.symbol,
      @required this.companyname,
      @required this.exchange,

      //Notifier
      @required this.page0Input,
      @required this.page1Input,
      @required this.page0Unit,
      @required this.page2Input,
      @required this.page2Unit,
      @required this.page3Input,

      //Logic
      @required this.principleDate,
      @required this.principlePrice,

      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply leave it out of the constructor. But keep in mind that this means the value of id will always be `null` after creating the object until you assign a value to it afterwards.

```
    NotifierInstance({
      @required this.symbol,
      @required this.companyname,
      @required this.exchange,

      //Notifier
      @required this.page0Input,
      @required this.page1Input,
      @required this.page0Unit,
      @required this.page2Input,
      @required this.page2Unit,
      @required this.page3Input,

      //Logic
      @required this.principleDate,
      @required this.principlePrice,

      });
```

Comment: If I initialize it like int id = 0; it shouldn't show null right? Also I guess I can just use a ?. to check if null

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for helping me!